# Conditional Expectation of multivariable function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which is not independent.
Also, I have a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I know that for any fixed $y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X,y)]=h(y),$$ where $h$ Is known. Is it right to say

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X,Y)|Y=y]=h(y)?$$ This sounds correct to me but I don’t know how to justify it theoretically. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot think of a proof. :(

Comment: Why $\mathbb{E}[g(X,Y | Y)]=h(Y)$? Seems nejimban has a counter example below. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can claim that $$E[g(X,Y)|Y=y]=E[g(X,y)|Y=y]$$ but you cannot go further by removing the conditioning.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $Y=X$ with $X$ symmetric, e.g., $X\sim\cal N(0,1)$. Take $g(x,y):=xy$ and $h(y):\equiv0$. Then
$$\Bbb E[g(X,y)]=y\,\Bbb E[X]=0=h(y)$$ for any $y\in\Bbb R$, but
$$\Bbb E[g(X,Y)\mid Y=y]=y^2\neq h(y).$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there any extra conditions can guarantee the statement holds?

Comment: @Jsi23484: I can't see any simple extra condition at the moment. Remember that the existence of the conditional expectation $H(Y):=\Bbb E[g(X,Y)\mid Y]$ is a statement over the *whole* $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y)$, which can be very large. It says that $\Bbb E[H(Y)\mathbf 1_{\{Y\in B\}}]=\Bbb E[g(X,Y)\mathbf 1_{\{Y\in B\}}]$ for *all* $B\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$ (and not just for $B$ of the form $B=\{y\}$ with $y\in\Bbb R$).